# How to find an authentic curry in Aarhus Denmark

Tags: food-and-drink, denmark

I'm visiting Aarhus Denmark for a month and really enjoy a good curry once in a while. I've looked on Trip Advisor, but no joy.

Comment: Can you tell us what you mean by a "proper" curry?

Comment: At first glance, google maps shows 3 Indian restaurants in Aarhus.

Comment: Proper meaning authentic. The places I've found, both through Google maps and Trip Advisor seem to be Chinese restaurants that serve curry and the reviews were bad :(

Comment: Love to hear why this deserves a -1

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is based on a subjective criteria that will draw opinions, not answers. We encourage questions that can be answered not discussed

Comment: Guys, whether or not a curry authentically follows a real Indian/south Asian recipe (you do mean Indian, right?), or is an oily gloop of food colourings with a few token spices added, is a question of ingredients not opinion...

Comment: Food opinions aside, there is an ex-pat organization of Indians in Aarhus which which might  have suggestions on where to find authentic cuisine: contact@indiansinaarhus.com

Comment: Honestly, I would have thought most of the questions in the Travel section would be on opinion. "Tipping in Denmark", "Where to park a car near Hirtshals", "Are cheap “programmable” combination padlocks known to change their own combinations?", etc. Go ahead and delete the question, it's not that important :)

Comment: A good tip for finding more authentic dishes somewhere is to search on an ingredient that is more common in the authentic stuff than the inauthentic. I did a quick search on 'paneer Aarhus' and found these guys: https://www.facebook.com/IndianInAarhus/ There's a few potential leads in the feed. For example: https://www.facebook.com/IndianInAarhus/photos/a.10150152994798888.292481.276905203887/10154160883393888/?type=3&theater and many of the cultural events will likely have authentic food

Comment: Just saying...  "Are cheap “programmable” combination padlocks known to change their own combinations?" Is not opinion based, they either are known to do so, or they aren't.

Comment: @JSLavertu I disagree. One person could think they are known to, another person could think they're not known to...these are opinions.

Comment: @user568458 Cheers, that is some good information, I never would have thought to search in that way!

Comment: And by agregating these opinions, we can easily determine if they actually have a reputation or if its only outliers. Not subjective.

Comment: Generally I try to figure out from the menu if it is a Bangladeshi establishment. Mostly misplaced O's are very common in their menu(English) and that gives them up. Most of the curry restaurants in Europe are Bangladeshi's (horrible cooks except for a very few) and forget about authenticity of the food. As @user568458 mentioned cultural events are your best bet to find authentic food.

Comment: @AndrewFox "Authentic" - meaning Autehntically British, where the idea of "curry" and dishes like Tikka Masla and Balti originate? Authentically Indian/Pakistaini/Bangladeshi? Somewhere that specialises in a reasonable local cuisine rather than trying to do all of the subconinent (eg Gujarati, Kashimiri, whatever)?

Comment: By the way, I don't feel this is opinion based, although it might be unclear. The question is "how to find" **not** "where is the best curry place in Aarhus?"

Comment: @CMaster I meant authentic as in East Indian type curry :) also, I edited my title to say "HOW" so it would draw answers and not opinions.

Comment: Voted to reopen after title change

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Asian Wok Restaurant advertise Tamil / South Indian dishes](https://www.facebook.com/IndianInAarhus/photos/a.10150152994798888.292481.276905203887/10154160883393888/?type=3&theater) that are not especially known in the west, and they appear to have the seal of approval of Aarhus's Indian community. From the way they advertise it, it looks like they do authentic south Asian food as a special rather than routine.

I'd suggest going there, not feeling too limited by the menu, and just asking them about what specific authentic dishes (particularly Tamil or South Indian) you're interested in. Independent or family run places can sometimes serve more than the popular Westernised menu suggests, e.g. they might be able to do some staples they normally only cook for staff or friends, or might be willing to serve you the more authentic version of a dish that they would normally westernise if you can convince them you know what you're talking about and won't run screaming from the spiciness or texture...

---

A good approach to finding things like this is to pick a dish or ingredient that is less common in inauthentic cuisine but more common in authentic cuisine, and search on that. "Curry" will always find more westernised Indian/South Asian food, for example, but a quick search on "paneer Aarhus" turned up the [Indians in Aarhus facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/IndianInAarhus). If there's a particular type of authentic Indian / South Asian dish you're interested in, search on that.

Looking at the discussion, it looks like the most reliable place to find authentic food might be cultural events. Seems like Indians in Aarhus don't find it easy to find authentic Indian food either ([example](https://www.facebook.com/IndianInAarhus/photos/a.10150152994798888.292481.276905203887/10152211483878888/?type=1&theater)).

Contacting this group directly is probably not a bad idea.

---

<sub>Note: this assumes you really do mean "authentic", and not "similar to Indian restaurants in Canada"...</sub>